# Select - Rows for Columns possible?

Tags: php, mysql, select

i have this select:

```
SELECT 
  a.`cod_oportunidade`,
  b.nome nome_cliente,
  c.descricao estado,
  d.descricao cidade,
  e.nome nome_funcionario_criou,
  f.nome nome_funcionario_resp,
  i.`descricao`,
  h.`valor`
FROM
  oportunidades_clientes a 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN empresas_clientes b 
    ON b.cod_cliente = a.cod_cliente 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN sistema_estados c 
    ON c.cod_estado = b.cod_estado 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN sistema_cidades d 
    ON d.cod_cidade = b.cod_cidade 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN empresas_funcionario e 
    ON e.cod_funcionario = a.cod_funcionario_criou 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN empresas_funcionario f 
    ON f.cod_funcionario = a.cod_funcionario_resp 
  JOIN formulario_valor h 
    ON h.`cod_oportunidade` = a.`cod_oportunidade` 
  JOIN formulario_campo i 
    ON i.`cod_campo` = h.`cod_campo` 
WHERE 1 = 1 
  AND a.`cod_oportunidade` = 3
```

The result is therefore:
[image: result]

My question is... Need to inves need to stay several lines that the result is only one line. The data in the column "descricao" must be as columns ...

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12004603/mysql-pivot-row-into-dynamic-number-of-columns

Comment: @PaulF this does not solve my problem because in this example they are using summing and in my case also has texts, cannot summing.

Comment: Check out other links for pivoting rows to columns - which is what you want if I understand your question correctly. If I am wrong, it may help us if you can show your expected result rather than just repeating "My question is ....."

Comment: @PaulF I understood what you meant, but when I opened this topic was really because they do not found something i need, all the contents that are found concerning the sums or calculations, and in my case is a text. But thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0):

The [implode()](http://php.net/implode) function will separate an array (columns from a database) with whatever character you prefer, in your case a pipe:

```
$mysqli = mysqli_connect("host","user","pass","db"); 
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT ...");
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo implode(" | ", $row) . '<br />';
}
```

Comment: My question is... Need to inves need to stay several lines that the result is only one line. The data in the column "descricao" must be as columns ...